# Listening to a collection's function call in Backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to sniff out when filterMe is called so I can update the view:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: '/myapi',
    filterMe: function() {
        return this.where({tag: "A"});
    }
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'div',
    initialize: function() {
        var that = this;
        //Anytime I call filterMe, I need to update the view with filtered data
        this.listenTo(my_collection, 'filterMe', this.render);
        my_collection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                that.render();
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        ...
    }
)};

var my_collection = new MyCollection();
var my_view = new MyView();
```

Need to fire render function anytime filterMe is performed. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
filterMe: function() {
    this.trigger("filterMe");
    return this.where({tag: "A"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger an event in 'filterMe' function and listen to it in the view.
Try this:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: '/myapi',
    filterMe: function() {
        //trigger a custom event that will be listened in the view
        this.trigger('filtered'); 
        return this.where({tag: "A"});
    }
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'div',
    initialize: function() {
        var that = this;
        //listen to custom event triggered in 'filterme' function
        my_collection.on('filtered',$.proxy(this.render, this));
        my_collection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                that.render();
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        ...
    }
)};

var my_collection = new MyCollection();
var my_view = new MyView();
```

I guess this is what you want. Please try this and let me know

Comment: Mention not. Please +1 my answer if it was helpful ;)